# Handling System hang in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I am facing a problem regarding implementation for Robot testcases for System Hang.

```
*** Settings ***
Library      SSHLibrary


*** Test Cases ***

Process Crash Dump
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    50sec    10sec    Execute Command    echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
    Should Be Equal   1      1
```

Here while "Execute Command     echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger" the testcase is getting stucked up and not proceeding furthur. Is there any kind of mechanism to come out after giving the command and later i'll check for system to start.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is resolved, by using

```
Start Command  echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Which issues command and exits. Then I am doing my stuff to check System is active or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a timeout on a testcase with the `[Timeout]` setting in a testcase, or `Test Timeout` in the suite settings. See [Test case time](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#test-case-timeout) out in the robot framework users guide. From the documentation:

> If there is a timeout, the keyword running is stopped at the
>   expiration of the timeout and the test case fails. However, keywords
>   executed as test teardown are not interrupted if a test timeout
>   occurs, because they are normally engaged in important clean-up
>   activities. If necessary, it is possible to interrupt also these
>   keywords with user keyword timeouts.

Comment: The documentation is out of date. It was true when RF was multi-threaded, but it has been single-threaded for a long time. Keywords cannot be stopped. Execute this in a test with a 1 second timeout: Evaluate time.sleep(10) time. You will find that it takes > 10 seconds for it to fail.

Comment: @ombre42: are you certain about that? I just tested your scenario, sleeping for 30 seconds with a five second timeout, and the evaluate keyword timed out after 5 seconds. This is on OSX; I haven't tried it on windows. Looking at the code I see it uses a threaded timer to manage the timeout.

Comment: Thank you for giving reply. I have used Start Command  echo c > /proc/sysrq-trigger, which worked for me

Comment: @BryanOakley yeah I forgot its a Windows thing. This has been explained in the forums, but the user guide makes no mention of timeouts being useless on Windows.